# Field with default value appears as optional in schema

Tags: django, drf-spectacular

Describe the bug
My code has the following model with a boolean field, `published`, with a default value of `false`

```
class PublishableModel(models.Model):
    """Fields used to determine if and when something is published."""
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

However, the schema that drf-spectacular produces shows published as optional.

For example:

```
/**
 * 
 * @type {boolean}
 * @memberof Article
 */
published?: boolean;
```

**Expected behavior**: Since there is a default value - all response types should appear in the required section of the model for methods that return an Article but optional for methods that are creating an Article.

**Update:** drf-spectacular [does indeed provide a way](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client_generation.html) to distinguish between request and response types using the "COMPONENT_SPLIT_REQUEST=True" setting.

However the types it emits are still the same for both Req/Res with a default parameter, so I still don't see how to leverage this in my situation. My expected behavior would still be that Res type would have the `published` field marked as required.

Comment: Is it possible this is the documentation of a serializer, not the actual model?

Comment: @vinkomlacic: say more? do I have to annotate the serializer's for models that inherit from this abstract model?

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue[^1](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/issues/810) about it which shows a couple of workarounds. It also has a response that explains the reasoning.

At the moment, you can use one of these workarounds:

1. create different serializers for requests and responses, and make all fields for the response serializer readonly.
2. Create a custom post-processing hook that sets all fields to required for response serializers (see the github issue for an example)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. tfranzel also responded to my original issue report [suggesting](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/issues/920#issuecomment-1413425094) a modification in the Serializer.